# Display flickering Lenovo SL500 with Windows7

Tags: windows-7

Recently I have updated my laptop Lenovo SL500 to windows7, and now I am facing an issue like whenever I use one more programs opened and at them same time, the display starts flickering unless those windows are not minimized, there is no problem if only one window at the screen.

Please advise how I can resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you updated to the latest drivers from Lenovo?

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have found others facing the same issue but then [here](http://www.futurehardware.com/notebook-tablet-pcs/1010.htm#post5546) are some solutions that you can try out, just check them out and see if they are helping.

Comment: It would be nice if you provide at least a quick overview of the different solutions. Links are likely to die and in that case your answer will no longer be of any help.